# Custom TabControl - Adding Controls with Designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, windows-forms-designer

Long story short, I created a custom winform `TabControl`:

```
public sealed class MyTabControl : TabControl
```

And I can't find a way to add other controls to its `TabPages`. When I drag and drop any kind of `Control` (a `Button`, for example, or a `Panel`) on the top of a `TabPage` display area, it's added to the `Form` instead of being added to the page itself. Anyone can explain me why and how to implement `Designer` interaction to my custom `Control`?

Comment: If you have not registered any designer for `MyTabControl ` the designer of `TabControl` will be used and every thing will work fine. Tab headers area can not be a drop target for your controls. You can drop controls in a `TabPage` but not at header area.

Comment: Does your custom TabControl use custom TabPages, too? Or does it use standard TabPage? Did you try to put your button on the header area or on the client area? What does your MyTabControl different from standard TabControl? When i try the same (where MyTabControl does nothing special) everything works fine (VS2015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add your "MyTabcontrol" to tool box.

**How to do that:**

On the Tools menu, click Choose Toolbox Items.

On the .NET Framework Components tab, click Browse.

In the Open File box, locate the DLL that was built when you created the UserControl control.

**Then Drag UserControl from the toolbox to Form.**

Then it works.

Here is the KB link from Microsoft.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/813450

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. The control is still not reactive to changes.